# Can an attribute require inheritance or implementation of a class or interface?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, custom-attributes, system.reflection

When attempting to apply the `System.AttributeUsage` attribute to a class, Visual Studio will show the error `"Attribute 'AttributeUsage' is only valid on classes derived from System.Attribute"`.  Is it possible to specify such a requirement for a custom attribute?

Imagine an attribute class `CommandAttribute`, which would specify the name of a command.  It should only be present on classes which implement `ICommand` so that we can guarantee that methods like `ExecuteCommand(...)` exist on the class.

I can of course use reflection to check that the applied classes implement the interface at run time, but ideally we could enforce this at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not directly supported by the C# language.

However, you can write [your own code analysis rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix) using the .NET Compiler Platform (aka Roslyn) and enforce that condition yourself.